# Perl inline replace in shell script not working as expected

Tags: regex, bash, perl, shell

I have a perl inline replace command in a shell script that isn't working for some reason. With below command, its replacing all ":" with replacement string in the perl command.

When I manually ssh to the box and running the perl command works as expected.

```
ssh host "cd /x/somedirectory && perl -pi -e 's#\${somehost}:\${someport}#10.20.30.40:8443#g' config/app.properties"
```

### Edit1

Please note that `$somehost` and `$someport` are NOT shell variables. I'm looking for a literal text replacement.

What am I doing wrong? I tried using different delimiters, escaping `{` and `}` etc but still no luck.

Comment: `somehost` and `someport` must not be defined then.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I see what you are saying now. `$somehost` and `$someport` are not shell variables. I'm looking for a literal text replacement. I'm editing the question

Comment: Figuring out escapes in a one-liner inside a shell script is like trying to train ants to juggle. Just do the whole thing in Perl using [`Net::SSH`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH). Or failing that, put the code from the one-liner inside a file, and run it like `ssh host "perl -pi code.pl /x/somedir/config/app.properties`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a single-quoted shell literal from a string, escape `'` by replacing them with `'\''`.

To create a double-quoted shell literal from a string, escape `\`, `"` and `$` by prefixing them with `\`.

---

The Perl command you want is

```
s#\${somehost}:\${someport}#10.20.30.40:8443#g
```

So the remote shell command you want is

```
perl -pi -e 's#\${somehost}:\${someport}#10.20.30.40:8443#g' config/app.properties
```

So the local shell command you want is

```
ssh host 'perl -pi -e '\''s#\${somehost}:\${someport}#10.20.30.40:8443#g'\'' config/app.properties'
```

or

```
ssh host "perl -pi -e 's#\\\${somehost}:\\\${someport}#10.20.30.40:8443#g' config/app.properties"
```

[Removed `cd /x/somedirectory &&` to keep things simple. Just add it back in.]

Comment: Both versions I posted work. Aside from doing this every day, I have tested them. Did you miscopy something (e.g. used `"` instead of `'`)? Or maybe you're not using bash (on both machines) as tagged?

Comment: I tried this `ssh host "perl -pi -e '\''s#\${somehost}:\${someport}#10.20.30.40:8443#g'\'' /x/web/STAGE2MS034/paymentapiplatformserv/config/app.properties"`. I get `bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''`

Comment: That's doesn't match either of my solutions. You used `"`, so you need to use the escape mechanism for `"`, but you used the escape mechanism for `'`. Either use the appropriate escape mechanism (second solution), or use `'` instead of `"` (first solution).

Comment: Ahh..thanks that works. One day I'll get better at bash

Comment: Just add each layer of escaping one at a time as i showed. // `'abc'\''def'` is `'abc'` (`abc`), `\'` (`'`), and `'def'` (`def`) one after the other, resulting in `abc'def`.

Answer (score 2):

The shell on the remote machine will perform another level of escaping. To receive the sequence `\$` on the remote machine you have to send the sequence `\\\$`:

```
ssh host "cd /x/somedirectory && perl -pi -e 
    's#\\\${somehost}:\\\${someport}#10.20.30.40:8443#g' config/app.properties"
```

Comment: Note: Only works if you remove the line break or if you add `\\ ` before the line break.

Answer (score 2):

So, you can write Perl...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::OpenSSH;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host);
my $old = quotemeta("${somehost}:${someport}");
$ssh->system('cd', $some_directory, \\'&&',
             'perl', '-pi', '-e',
             "s|$old|10.20.30.40:8443|g",
             'config/app.properties');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `ssh` command with here-doc and avoid all escaping:

```
ssh -t -t host<<'EOF'
cd /x/somedirectory &&
    perl -i -pe 's#\${somehost}:\${someport}#10.20.30.40:8443#g' config/app.properties
exit
EOF
```

Comment: still no luck. You forgot `{` and `}` in your answer. I added them but I get same result

Comment: @nilesh Are you trying to replace the literal text `${somehost}`, or the value of the bash variable `$somehost`?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot you got it. I'm trying to replace literal text. `$somehost` and `$someport` are not shell variables

Comment: @anubhava sorry for the confusion, `$somehost` and `$someport` are not shell variables. I'm looking for a literal text replacement

Comment: `${somehost} != $somehost` as a literal text value.

Comment: @nilesh: Also notice use of `'EOF'` at start to avoid expansion of `$`

Comment: `perl -pei 'foo'` is equivalent to `perl -pe 'i' foo` (i.e. run the code `i` on file `foo`), you need `perl -i -pe 'foo'`. Also, you have to escape the `$` in the regex so it doesn't mean end-of-line: `perl -i -pe 's#\${somehost}:\${someport}#10.20.30.40:8443#g'`

Comment: Thanks so much @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, yes of course `$` needs to be escaped. I just edited.